# Javascript to modify web content on cell click

Tags: javascript, ios, wkwebview, whatsapp

I am working in an app for iOS with WhatsApp Web, and I am giving a new look to it inside the app.

I am implementing some JS functions to a WkWebView such change width values, background colors and other stuff, but I am stuck in a point.

As you may or may not know, the WhatsApp Web App, has two main columns, one of them shows the chats, and the other one shows the selected chat. Like this:

[image: WhatsApp Web sample image]

At this moment, I have managed to load the web app on a wkWebView and give the chats column the 100% of the device width. But now I need to catch the click on "cell" from this column in order to change the width value to the other side of the web app.

Other problem seems to be that on an iPhone I need to tap twice in the "cell" to make it load the chat data in the right column. So the question is, can anyone help me to solve my doubts or give me a little hint with it?

Thanks a lot!
M.W.

Comment: Can we see the code you've right now?

Comment: Just a heads up: https://www.cultofmac.com/314343/use-a-third-party-whatsapp-client-and-you-could-be-banned-for-life/

Comment: The code can be executed in the javascript console, in the app there is just a JS Caller when the web view is loaded, nothing interesting to show.

Comment: The app is not a third party api like whatsapp+, the app just uses the web.whatsapp.com interface, in the mobile app. Nothing ilegal. Just shows a custom web view with the WhatsApp web content.

Comment: Any solution ? @wazowski

Comment: I have added a solution in the next post :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, some days of research about JS functions I have managed to detect the touches events in the web view. The sentence you can test in the web.whatsapp.com java console is like this:

```
function handleStart(evt) {
   evt.preventDefault();
   console.log('touchstart');
}
elements=document.getElementsByClassName('NAME');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
   elements[i].addEventListener("touchstart", handleStart, false);
}
```

The `evt.preventDefault();` prevents the execution of the flow of the touch, so if you want it to work, just comment this line.

With this functions you can handle touch start, touch end, touch move, and some more...

Other thing, if you want to execute this sentence in a WkWbView on iOS, you just need to call a JS function like this:

```
jsString = @"function handleStart(evt) {evt.preventDefault();console.log('touchstart.');} \
                    elements=document.getElementsByClassName('NAME'); \
                    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) { \
                        elements[i].addEventListener('touchstart', handleStart, false); \
                    }";
[self callJS:jsString];
```

And the **callJS** function will need to call this:

```
[_wkWebView evaluateJavaScript:jsString completionHandler:^(id response, NSError *error) {
    if (error)
        NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
}];
```

And in ordet to 'read' the click on the cell of the left column with out mess with the other events, you can handle the tap with click event like this:

```
elements=document.getElementsByClassName('NAME');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
   elements[i].addEventListener('click', 'console.log('click')', false);
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: What is 'NAME' for whatsapp @wazowski ?

Comment: NAME is the name of the class you want to work with. Something like this on a div from a website: `<div class="_1jjYO">This is a div in a web</div>` In this case 'NAME' is '_1jiYO'.